# ActiveRecord querying item based on multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I feel like this is a common issue, but I wasn't totally sure how to word what I'm trying to solve:

I have 2 models:

Items & Tags

each Item has_many tags

if I'm filtering my items by tags, and lets say I want to find all items with "TAG X & TAG Y" or "TAG B & TAG C" what would that query look like with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the column you use to identify a `Tag` is called `name`, you could add a method as follows:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  # Query via raw SQL
  def self.tagged(*tag_sets)
    tag_sets.map { |tag_names|
      joins(:tags).
        where('tags.name' => tag_names).
        group('items.id').
        having("count(*) = #{tag_names.size}").to_sql
    }.join(' UNION ')
    find_by_sql(big_query)
  end

  # Query via Arel
  def self.tagged_using_arel(*tag_sets)
    items_table = arel_table
    union = tag_sets.map { |tag_names|
      joins(:tags).
        where('tags.name' => tag_names).
        group('items.id').
        having("count(*) = #{tag_names.size}")
    }.reduce { |acc, rel| acc.union(rel) }
    from(items_table.create_table_alias(union, :items))
  end
end


items = Item.tagged(%W[X Y], %W[Z])
```

Note, the above is a bit messy (i.e. playing either raw SQL or Arel) since Rails currently has no way of merging relations with `OR`. That gift is coming [in Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9e42cf019f2417473e7dcbfcb885709fa2709f89).

Here's the same this as above written using arel:

Comment: But won't that array only act like "or"? I need to specifically say, "Items with tag X and tag Y, or items with tag Z"

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood your question twice, give me a sec.

Comment: Are you looking for items tagged with X and Y alone? or would W, X, and Y be appropriate too?

Comment: so in this case, I would say I want to return everything that matches X & Y alone (i.e. items that are tagged with both), + any item tagged with W.

Comment: Just to be clear: Given Item1[W, X, Y], Item2[W, Z], Item3[Z], Item4[X, Y], you'd expect all to show up in the results not just Item3 and Item4?

Comment: Nope, I would expect item 4 and 1 (matches x & y), and items 2 (matching w), item3 would not match... item5[x], and item6[y] would also not match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79073/discussion-between-faraz-and-elliot).

Answer (score 0):

Why not something as simple as

```
class Item
  has_many :tags
  scope :by_tags, ->(tag_set){
      tag_set.each_with_object(scoped) do |tag, ar|
        ar.by_tag(tag)
      end 
  }

  scope :by_tag, ->(tag){
    joins(:tags).where(tags:{ name: tag })
  }
```

This will join them as an AND clause and can be called with

```
Item.by_tags(['X','Y'])
```